# Why this gallery is not responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I don't know what should I change in this gallery code to make this responsive on mobile phone. Everything is good when I show it on computer screen but on mobile screen it's broken.

I've already tried different bootstrap command to make this code responsive but without any success.

Full gallery code bellow:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ga9k0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use media queries, for example:

```
/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Another example here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

And here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Look at the actual device resolution:

http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats